# How to make pagination "Next" button not look disabled in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables, disabled-control

I'm using Datatables pagination to show my records. My problem is that when I go to the end of my table using the "next" button of the table, this button becomes disable.
I want this button not to look Disable.
I have tried this :

```
$j('#buttonID').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$j('#buttonID').disable(true);
$j('#buttonID').prop('disabled', false);
```

but this are not working.
Can anybody help me with an example?

Comment: I believe you need to remove the disabled attribute, not just change it's value

Comment: So style it to look whatever you prefer.

Comment: Odd request. By disabling the button it makes it obvious to your users they've reached the end of the result set. Why would you not want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the disabling effect you have to remove the attribute `disabled` at all since `disabled="true"` or `disabled="false"` are considered as `disabled`, you could use **[`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)**:

```
$j('#buttonID').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#buttonID').removeAttr('disabled');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button disabled="true">Button 1</button>
<button disabled="false">Button 2</button>
<button disabled>Button 3</button>

<button id="buttonID" disabled>Button 4</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Datatables will set the css class "disabled" on the next button when you reach the end.

To remove the class you will have to call.

```
$("#buttonID").removeClass("disabled")
```

The problem is that you can not call this once initialy, because datatables might disable the button afterwards, so the best thing would be to put this call into the callback after you have navigated in DT.

```
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        $("#buttonID").removeClass("disabled")
    }
});
```

Something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').removeAttribute('disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `CSS` for disabled button in `DataTable` `CSS` like:

this is `CSS` for enable anchor :

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display: inline-block;
   min-width: 1.5em;
   padding: 0.5em 1em;
   margin-left: 2px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #333 !important;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 2px;
}
```

copy this `CSS` to your disable anchor `CSS`.

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:hover, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:active {
   cursor: default;
   color: #666 !important;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   background: transparent;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```